# How to click in an Excel cell and run a command line contained in that cell or in an adjacent cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out the following:

- I have a Excel sheet where I feed some parameters daily and it concatenates those to run an application in command line.
- The sheet generates a total of 28 commands (lines), plus the first one that reaches the application folder
- Then I have to copy all those command and paste in an .bat, and run.

I wish:

- I could add a Button that runs all the 29 commands (lines) with a click;
- Click in any of the 28 commands cells to run only that command (the click being pretty much like in this example, but the click should run what is in that cell...)

Here an example of the concatenated sheet from where I copy and paste in the .bat file

The parameters that are different between commands are further right, not shown here:

[image]

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: To me it looks [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956651/execute-a-command-in-command-prompt-using-excel-vba?answertab=votes#tab-top) could be a good starting point for your work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write this whole thing out, because I don't know what your files or structure looks like.  All you have to do is load in the excel sheet information to the code and let the loop go. It will add each line to the batch file. You can add a shell to automatically run it... but if you do you might need a small pause or delay.

```
    Sub Blah()


    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim F As File
    Dim F2 As TextStream
    Dim BatchFile As String
    'Also, need to load in excel stuff up here.

    BatchFile = ("C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Documents\FileName.bat")
    Set F2 = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Documents\FileName.bat")
    RowNum = 1
    On Error GoTo Errs:
    S = ""
    Do Until Worksheet.Cells(RowNum, 1).value = ""

    S = S & workshee.Cells(RowNum, 1) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)

    RowNum = RowNum + 1
    Loop
Errs:

    F2.Write S

    End Sub
```